# Error : You don't have an extension for debugging 'plain text'. should we find a 'plain text' extension the marketplace?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, text

I unable to run this code : a=hello  print(a[2]),when I try to run on vs code it gives me an error you don't have an extension for debugging plain text and recommend to download 2 extension.
I downloaded from list but nothing is working this error come again and again what should I do?

Comment: The code is wrong and the file is not saved as python